# What does $this[$variable] mean in php?

Tags: php, this

I was reading through [this code](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/blob/12c5db90322f61d4d48e1bb534bb94382d17e317/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php#L152):

```
public function registerService($name, Closure $closure, $shared = true) {
        $name = $this->sanitizeName($name);
        if (isset($this[$name]))  {
            unset($this[$name]);
        }
        if ($shared) {
            $this[$name] = $closure;
        } else {
            $this[$name] = parent::factory($closure);
        }
}
```

and don't understand what `$this[$name]` means. How can $this be accessed as an array? What exactly is happening here?

I goggled "$this as array" and read the [$this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) again but did not find anything explaining this syntax.

Comment: In that doc, it clearly says, $this is a reference to the calling object. See the example two as well. 
Check your class file where you have that funciton , $name must be the property of that class.  If you want to use $name as an array, you may need to change your function  sanitizeName and also  check where you are calling that registerService function. You have to pass array as first variable while calling that function.

Comment: [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) Interface is how.

Comment: @Bee: I am not asking what $this does in gerneral. I don't want to use $name as an array. I don't think you understood what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `SimpleContainer` extends `Pimple\Container`, which implements `\ArrayAccess`, which enables array-like syntax on your object through a number of methods [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

Answer (score 0):

I came in because I wanted to know about this.

After I saw Havenard's answer and then I tested it, I found out.

```
class A implements \ArrayAccess
{
    private $array;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->array = array("one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3);
    }
    public function WhatDoesThisArray($val1)
    {
        $this[$val1] = 99;
        $this[$val1];
        var_dump($this[$val1]);
        echo $this[$val1];
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        echo "call offsetExists\n";
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        echo "call offsetGet($offset)\n";
        return $this->array[$offset];
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        echo "call offsetUnset\n";
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        echo "call offsetSet\n";
        $this->array[$offset] = $value;
    }
}

/* Test */
$testClass = new A();
$testClass->WhatDoesThisArray("two");

/* Result */
call offsetSet
call offsetGet(two)
call offsetGet(two)
int(99)
call offsetGet(two)
99
```

in class like [Class A implements \ArrayAccess]

$this[$var]; **means** $this->offsetGet($var);

$this[$var] = $value; **means** $this->offsetSet($var, $value);

I hope it helped. Thanks Havenard!

Answer (score -1):

$this is indicative of a classwide variable. By the looks of the code the class extends container and implements an icontainer, being that it has no constructor in the class you've shown itself, its most likely in the class it extends. There is also a registerParameter class that is likely called before the registerService class

```
public function registerParameter($name, $value) {
    $this[$name] = $value;
}
```

Its purpose is to push new values to the variable pulled in the service register

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Considering you provided a single page of code and asked how do, im pretty sure the description is enough. I said it extended the container class, im not going to look through the entire application to find the container class as that is up to you to do. I also stated the items you needed were in the class it extends, which it is.